# How to change the 'Date posted' into 'hours, minutes...'

Tags: jquery, django, datetime

I currently have a system where when a user posts a question it states the date below.

Example: 3 answers · Follow · April 12, 2011, 5:14 p.m.

Instead of 'April 12, 2011, 5:14p.m.' I would like it to be 5 hours ago until its a full 24 hours ago then it switches to the full date.

Im using normal css, jquery, php ect to program this site and the platform im using in Django.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a css issue. CSS is for styling only.

Answer (score 3):

There is a handy little snippet over at django snippets to help you tackle that http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1409/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: [something called pretty date](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) from the John Resig himself...

Answer (score 0):

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is a handy tool for all kinds of date-related manipulation.